# Excel VBA code to create a text box that filers a specific column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a way to filter a column on a file, ideally what I would like to happen is to have someone enter a name in the text box and then the file will filter on that specific name.
I have been trying to look for a code to do it online but I have not been able to find one that works.

```
Active  Company Name        ID    Company Profile Owner
Yes     Company 1           B52     Profile 2     Jim
Yes     Company 2           B84     Profile 3     Jack
No      Company 3           B98     Profile 4     Ana
Yes     Company 4           B82     Profile 5     Jim
No      Company 5           B15     Profile 6     Ana
```

Basically on the text box the users will type the name of the owner and then the code will filter based the owner column to only show the records associated with that name.

Thank you

Comment: Data, Filter,Advanced Filter  allows you to define a cell as a criteria - type the name in there and the command will hide all but the rows you want.

Comment: Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    'Filter Name field in DBTable Table.
    Dim strFilter As String
    strFilter = "*" & [B5] & "*"
    Debug.Print strFilter
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DBtableTable").Range.AutoFilter _
     Field:=1, _
     Criteria1:=strFilter, _
     Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub

Comment: the text box is in the worksheet,at least that is what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer because I'm board, I wanted to try input boxes. Install these two macros and Insert two buttons on row 1, Assign the macros to the buttons. The first button will use input boxes to ask what column # you want to filter, and the second as for the criteria to filter. The second macro clears the filter.

```
Sub Button3_Click()
Dim fldInput As String
Dim criInput As String
fldInput = InputBox("Enter the Column # to Filter")
criInput = InputBox("Enter the String to filter on")

    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=fldInput, Criteria1:=criInput
    End With
End Sub

Sub Button4_Click()
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter
End Sub
```